# Customize year title for v-date-picker

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a date picker with Japanese locale

```
            <v-date-picker
            locale="ja-jp"
        ></v-date-picker>
```

This helps to keep kanjis for week/month/year.
But is there any way to customize the year line to add Japanese era there? Or maybe there is any solution for this era problem in vue?
So 2021年 becomes 2021年 (3令和)

Comment: Seems like :year-format should work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
:year-format="date => getJapaneseEraYear(new Date(date).getFullYear())"
```